# c++ iterator with template

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a problem about how to use iterator under the template manner.
Here is an example I am trying to do, the problem is that, inside the for loop how can I initial the iterator pp ?

I have read a similar question, but I cannot fully understand that since I am a beginner.
[What should the iterator type be in this C++ template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219146/what-should-the-iterator-type-be-in-this-c-template)
Can anyone help and also provide some simple explanation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void my_print(std::vector<T> input){
    for(std::vector<T>::iterator pp = input.begin(); pp != input.end(); ++pp)
        std::cout << *pp << "\n";
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    std::vector<int> aa(10,9);
    my_print(aa);

    return 0;
}
```

error message I got:
‘std::vector::iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type

Comment: Having a nicer compiler: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<T>::iterator’ because ‘std::vector<T>’ is a dependent scope

Comment: Also, to avoid a costly copy, you should change to `my_print(std::vector<T> const &input)` and `const_iterator`.

Comment: With C++11, you may write `for (const auto& elem : input) { std::cout << elem << "\n"; }`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add a `typename` before the `iterator`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void my_print(std::vector<T> input)
{
    for (typename std::vector<T>::iterator pp = input.begin(); pp != input.end(); ++pp)
    {
        std::cout << *pp << "\n";
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> aa(10, 9);
    my_print(aa);

    return 0;
}
```

source: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/187603/template-function-vector-iterator-wont-compile

Comment: Can you explain why `typename` is necessary? What is the intuition behind it? Is it recommended to use `typename` or `class`?

Answer (score 4):

Like Dieter says, newer versions of gcc will pretty much tell you where typename is needed:

```
error: need 'typename' before 'std::vector<T>::iterator' 
       because 'std::vector<T>' is a dependent scope
```

Simple fix:

```
for(typename std::vector<T>::iterator pp = input.begin(); 
          pp != input.end(); ++pp)
```

Here is an explanation [Error with T::iterator, where template parameter T might be vector<int> or list<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735022/error-with-titerator-where-template-parameter-t-might-be-vectorint-or-list)

> Before a qualified dependent type, you need typename. Without
>   typename, there is a C++ parsing rule that says that qualified
>   dependent names should be parsed as non-types even if it leads to a
>   syntax error.

For a more comprehensive explanation, check out [Why is the keyword "typename" needed before qualified dependent names, and not before qualified independent names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584431/why-is-the-keyword-typename-needed-before-qualified-dependent-names-and-not-b)

Comment: Can you give a some what intuitiv explanation?